Why is exponential smoothing forecast the median of the forecast density?
I am reading Hyndman & Athanasopoulos "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" 2nd edition (FPP2). (I am aware that 3rd edition exists.) In the chapter about exponential smoothing, section 7.7 discusses forecasting with exponential smoothing state space models and says this:

ETS point forecasts are equal to the medians of the forecast distributions. For models with only additive components, the forecast distributions are normal, so the medians and means are equal. For ETS models with multiplicative errors, or with multiplicative seasonality, the point forecasts will not be equal to the means of the forecast distributions.
(Emphasis is mine)

I wonder about the first sentence. Is there something inherent in the state space model that makes the point forecast to be the median? Or is this simply the choice of the author of the ETS method? Since a state space model seamlessly (?) produces a density forecast, a user (such as the author) can pick whichever derived feature of the distribution as the point forecast, median being one of them.

I fully agree that the state space model produces probabilistic forecasts, and any one-dimensional property of a forecast distribution is a possible choice for a point forecast.
I think the authors make this choice in section 7.7 to relate to the exponential smoothing methods (e.g. Holt-Winters' method) presented in previous sections. These methods have no underlying stochastic model, but produce predictions for future observations. I think the authors define the point forecasts of the state space model such that they agree with the predictions from the exponential smoothing methods:

These forecasts are identical to the forecasts from Holt’s linear method, and also to those from model ETS(A,A,N). Thus, the point forecasts obtained from the method and from the two models that underlie the method are identical (assuming that the same parameter values are used).

They then call these values the ETS point forecast, although it is rather just the choice of point forecasts which yields agreement with the formulas derived in earlier sections.

Interesting! That could be it. But how come Holt's linear model's / Hold-Winters' method's forecast coincides with the median of the distribution obtained from the equivalent state space model? I searched the earlier sections of chapter 7, but the word median is not found there. (Let me know if you think I should post it as a separate question.)

@RichardHardy you cannot find the word median there since these methods do not use any kind of probability theory in their derivation. So the fact that the method's forecasts coincide with the state space model's median could be a) real coincidence, or b) the state space models were designed in a way as to get this agreement. The latter sounds more plausible to me.
